# Conditional formatting using vba?

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

Greetings to the team here,

During tha ast couple of days I am facing a problem which I was not able to find a solution for. Whenever I am using the VBA editor in excel, any changes that I am introducing have not a permanent result. To be more specific. I am trying to change the color of cells located in column K ( from row 92 to 95) based on some logical criteria of other cells.
A) If the corresponding cell of column H and the same row is less or equal to 2, then the K's cell should be red.
B) If the corresponding cell of column H and the same row is higher than 5, then the K's cell should be green.

I can do any changes or introduce new conditional rules but my spreadsheet is extended to a couple hundred of cells. Thus I need to find an efficient way.

By now the vba code is as simple as you can see below:

```
Sub FixCondFormat()

Dim i As Long, r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range

   For i = 92 To 95
       Set r1 = Range("E" & i)
       Set r2 = Range("H" & i)
       Set r3 = Range("K" & i)
       If r2.Value <= (2 * r1.Value) Then r3.Interior.Color = vbRed
       If r2.Value > (5 * r1.Value) Then r3.Interior.Color = vbGreen
   Next i

  End Sub
```

If I run this for my sheet, the changes are not permanent. What I mean by this, is that whenever cell values change I need to run this part of the code again and again. Bby introducing a new rule manualy the correspoding rules are permanent. See beow:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2AyN.png)

On the other hand though after running the code above there are not any rules intrpduced to the system for the cells 92 to 95 despite the fact that the corresponding colors are keep changing.

I need your help. Is ther a way to introduce these conditional rules by running only the code above?

Note that the values in cells of column H are a product of subraction of two other cells. Given the fact that inserting manually rule conditions this works fine, is there an alternative which I could be use here?I need the base of my condition to be the value of cells in H as it is.

Moreover, isn't there any way to automatically produce these conditional rules (as the ones shown in the picture above), only by executing a vba routine? I habe in mind the execution of a batch file, to make these changes and introduce these rules automatically.

Comment: Have You tried to put this code into WorkSheet_Change event?

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Following the corresponfing page for Change event I do not seem to understand how am I supposed to set up the cells in need. While trying to run the code above inside the                                                                 <<Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)>> the code does not run .

Answer (score 0):

Your code changes the the cell colour. That change is permanent. Yes, you will have to run the code again when values change. In order to have conditional formatting you must set conditional formats which your code doesn't do.

I wouldn't do it, either. That's because I don't like Excel to interfere with my VBA. A VBA solution would involve an even procedure like the one provided below. Install it in the code module of the worksheet on which your ranges are located. (It won't work if installed in a standard code module).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim Cell    As Range
    Dim Col     As Long
    Dim R1      As Double
    
    With Target
        For Each Cell In Target
            If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Columns("H")) Is Nothing Then
                R1 = Val(Cells(Cell.Row, "E").Value)
                Col = IIf(.Value <= (R1 * 2), vbRed, IIf(.Value > (5 * R1), vbGreen, 0))
                
                With Cells(Cell.Row, "K").Interior
                    If Col Then
                        .Color = Col
                    Else
                        .Pattern = xlNone
                    End If
                End With
            End If
        Next Cell
    End With
End Sub
```

This procedure will run when one or more cells in column H are changed, compare the new value with the value in column E and set the colour in column K accordingly.

Note that it may not run when the change in column H is caused by a change elsewhere, such as might be the case when column H contains a formula. In that case the trigger for the even procedure must be moved to the column or columns that case the change. If, for example, column H is a multiplication of numbers in columns F and G, you can let the change in either of these columns trigger the code.

Further note that you can't change more than one cell at a time under normal circumstances. Therefore the loop in my code appears superfluous. It will run only once. However, if you paste a block of values lifted from elsewhere then many cells would be changed in one go and my loop would take effect.

Comment: First things first, while running the code nside Worksheet_change, the target variable is initialized where exactly? What is the actual range of this variable?

 Secondly you are correct, values in the cells of column H are a product of subraction of two other cells. Given the fact that inserting manually rule conditions this works fine, is there an alternative which I could be use here?I need the base of my condition to be the value of cells in H as it is.

Comment: `Target` is the cell where the change took place. It is set by the change event (VBA) and needs not be in column H. It should be where the user makes the relevant change. Whether you change the colour in column K relative to the value in column H or in accordance with the change elsewhere that causes the value in column H to change is largely a matter of transparency. In my understanding both the colour in column K and the value in column H are determined by the same change elsewhere and should therefore both be linked to that same source.

Comment: ` If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Columns("H")) Is Nothing ` This is the code that triggers the action when the change occurred anywhere in column H. `Application.Intersect` returns a range object. If the change didn't occur in column H it will return `Nothing` and no action will be taken. You can change `Columns("H")` to the column where you want to capture the change that affects the value in column H.